# how to make ps show child processes that are listed at htop?

Tags: nautilus, process, htop

I am not being able to `ps -p $pid` of some processes that are listed at htop...

One very well known that I can point out is `nautilus` (so I think you can easly try it). There is a main process that `ps` can see, but there are 2 child processes listed on `htop` which pids bring nothing with `ps`...

how can I make `ps` see those child process? as some other commands like `gcore` can interact with them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found about LWP being the threads of a process, so I did this:

```
ps -A |grep nautilus #get the pid ex.: 3343
ps -L -p 3343 -o pid,nice,lwp,comm
```

`-L` option will show the threads!

So This will show all its threads, so you can ex. renice not only the process pid but also each thread! just use the value at LWP column as the pid to work at, like in:

```
renice -n 10 -p `ps -L -p 3343 -o lwp --no-headers |tr '\n' ' '`
```